# Finding distance to one of either the x or y coordinate

Tags: python, drawing, coordinates, distance, turtle-graphics

Using `turtle.distance()` we can find the distance from the current position (`turtle.position`) to the specified x,y coordinate. However, it doesn't appear that we can leave either option blank. Is there a simple way to find the distance from the turtle's current position to ONLY the x or ONLY the y coordinate?

The task is to draw a line that will turn around when it hits a 400x400 bounding box and the best way I can think of to do that is find out if it's in range of either the x or y value of the box.

Answer (score 1):

```
def check_bounds(pos,a_rect):
    rect_left = a_rect[0][0]
    rect_top = a_rect[0][1]
    rect_right = a_rect[1][0]
    rect_top = a_rect[1][1]
    hit_x = rect_left <= pos[0] <= rect_right 
    hit_y = rect_top <= pos[1] <= rect_bottom
    return hit_x and  hit_y  #the player has hit the box

box = [(50,50),(100,100)] #TL,BR
turtle_pos = (40,40)

check_bounds(turtle_pos,box)
```

of course you can simplify it.... just wanted it nice and verbose so OP could understand what's going on.